# Ссылки в сообщениях Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot

Подскажите как зашить в ссылку доп параметры?

Есть StoreBot для оценки ботов Telegram. Если написать ответ пользователю:

> перейдите в @StoreBot

то бот будет светится как ссылка, но ссылка просто на бота `https://telegram.me/storebot`.

Мне же нужен переход к боту с определением какого бота я буду оценивать `https://telegram.me/storebot?start=***_bot`.

p.s.: html-теги telegram не понимает. Если написать `<a href="">@StoreBot</a>`, то так и выведет с тегом.

Comment: нашел. Есть параметры sendMessage['parse_mode'] в которм указывается формат(Markdown, html) вывода сообщения!

Answer (score 4):

Как Вы уже сами определили - в API есть [**Formatting options**](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options). Работает это примерно так же, как и тут, на **SO**.

Помимо этого метода есть ещё два варианта решения Вашей задачи:

- вместо имени бота **@StoreBot** указывать просто ссылку
- воспользоваться встроенной клавиатурой с единственной кнопкой, при нажатии на которую пользователь будет направляться куда нужно

Если с первым вариантом всё предельно ясно, то со вторым чуть сложнее. Встроенная клавиатура, или [InlineKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup), это кнопки, которые прикрепляются непосредственно к сообщению, в отличие от обычной [ReplyKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup). **InlineKeyboardMarkup** состоит из массива кнопок [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton), у которых есть свойство **url**, задав которое, мы определяем поведение кнопки при нажатии на неё - переход по указанной ссылке. Выглядит такое решение очень элегантно.

Для того, чтобы отобразить встроенную клавиатуру, необходимо передать её в сообщении пользователю.